# Wave Expression Smooth/Linear Control

Tags: c#, math, expression, curve, maxscript

How can I create a function which allows me to control the roundness of a wave so I can transition between an Round Wave > Linear Wave > Inverted Round wave?

I've made a function which creates a Bounce wave, but i feel there may be a more effective way of writing this. You can see in the picture below, if I pass the function a Smoothness value of -1 it will be inverted, 0 will be linear, and 1.0 will create the round wave. Any value between those will just be a transition between.

[image]

You'll see in the function below ill be passing the following properties to the function...
waveWidth: controls the wide of a single wave
minVal: starting position of the wave on the Y axis
maxVal: controls the overall height of the wave, subtracting the minVal
numSamples: the number of points to plot along the curve
smoothness: 'not implemented yet' but would control whats described above

```
fn BuildBounceArc waveWidth:10 minVal:0 maxVal:10 numSamples:20 smoothness:1.0 =
(
    for i = 0 to numSamples do
    (
        ang = i * 180.0 / numSamples
        posZ = abs(sin(ang)) * (maxVal - minVal) + minVal
        posX = 1.0 * i / numSamples * waveWidth

        -- The line below is for plotting the points visually
        --point pos:[posX, 0, posZ] size:.5 wirecolor:green name:("ang_" + ang as string)
    )
)
```

Comment: Maybe mathexchange would be a nettet fit for your question

Comment: The curves in the image look like circles in different metrics (green: euclidean, base 2; pink: Manhattan, base 1; yellow: probably base 1/2). If this is what you want, just look up the according formulas

Comment: Could you just help figure out the equation for the yellow arc if anything. I can figure out the rest.

Comment: That could be `y = (r^0.5 - |x|^0.5)^2`. You could calculate the exponent with `e = 2^smoothness`.